# SQLite database : data folder persmission

Tags: android, sqlite

I am beginner in android developpement so I try to learn working with SQLite database. My problem is that I can't access to the contents of data folder in DDMS.
I created a simple Product table in "sample.sqlite" database using SQLiteBrowser and I copied It in assets folder but when I tried to access it, I get this error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime(10081): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Product (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Product
```

And when I check my data folder in the DDMS, I can't access to It's folders, I gess It's because of folder's permission: ("drwxrwx--x"=read only).
So can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to copy the sqlite table into assets folder. Once you create the table, you should be able to CURD on it using SQLiteOpenHelper class. I suggest you follow some tutorials like this before moving on:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

Comment: I don't know if you tried to access it with file explorer but SQlite informations are hidden. Follow @LoveForDroid suggestion.

Comment: What about data folder permission

Comment: @it4Astuces Are you using emulator or real device? The real device needs to be rooted for that purpose

Comment: I am using BlueStack emulator.

Comment: @LoveForDroid Can you please help here. It's very important to me

Comment: @LoveForDroid Thank you for your answers, i was a complete beginner at that time.
I did not know where to look
Good Luck!